# How to encrypt/decrypt floating point arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption

There are many questions and answers about encrypting/decrypting `Uint8` arrays. These might use `utf-8` or `utf-16` encodings and/or `codePointAt()`.  But what about longer data types - in my case floating points `Int32Array`s?

My preference would be to use the `CryptoJS` library. But the builtin `SubtleCrypto` might be considered as well.

Comment: Doesn't matter. They're all based on `ArrayBuffer`s, and you can (should) just create an `Uint8Array` view on your floating point data.

Comment: Javascript strings are inherently utf-16.

Comment: And no, encryption/decryption algorithms that operate on bytes do *not* use any string (character sequence) encodings or codepoints.